# How to deform a sphere to a half-sphere

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

I want to animate two spheres colliding that end up as one ying yang symbol.

[image: Storyboard]

The perfect solution in my eyes would be a way to reverse engineer it: deform a sphere (*fig. A*) with modifiers to a half piece of the symbol (*fig. B*).

**How to deform/morph a sphere to a half-sphere smootly and suitable for animation?**

I tried at first with the Boolean tool, but this is just way too glitchy. I tried Cloth and Softbody simulation too, but this costs too much time. I got the feeling a range of modifiers such as simple deform and displacement could work perfectly. Any clever ideas?

*Update 30 min later: I tried procedural modelling with modifiers to it, but it's clearly not so round as I want it to be. Plus there is a weird glitch. See blend file below.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you want shape A to morph towards shape B?

Comment: @moonboots yes. But in a way that it's suitable for a smooth animation.

Comment: Well...it depends. If you want a normal solution - moonboots can help. If you want a python solution, batFingers can help. And for procedural solution: Robin Betts can help. And you might think about using Shape Keys - which is a possible solution too.

Comment: @Chris I hope you will help with the Geometry Node solution

Comment: @jspr you first show 2 half spheres colliding then a sphere that is supposed to morph, these are 2 different things, so I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: @moonboots i would if i could :( but if you present the solution i can extend it that there are lots of half cubes making love with each other.....! :D

Comment: what about using shapekeys?

Comment: some intermediate pictures between A and B would be welcome imho

Comment: Thanks for this all, give me a second to provide more images and a better understanding!

Comment: how do you want to have the transitioning from the full sphere to the half sphere?

Comment: @Chris a simple dent I guess, imagine bending with a simple bend modifier and ease the value.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea for the "big" problem: the big problem is the direct morphing of a full sphere in the half twisted sphere. If you would first morph it to half sphere and then to twisted half sphere it would be no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a try:

[image]

I've twisted a sphere, kept an edge loop only:

[image]

Then used a *Screw* modifier to make it rotate from 360° to 180°, then gave it *Solidify*, *Bevel* and *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: woooooooooow ;)

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure this is what he wants, but anyway morphing is pretty hard to do in Blender, so that's another solution  ;)

Comment: i would bet he is not satisfied.... :D then he could have used my version with first morphing to half sphere :D but anyway....great solution again from you!!!

Comment: oh ok yes the Simple Deform modifier is a good idea, except he wants to begin with a full sphere

Comment: You could definitely use the round side of one of the spheres for an "optical illusion" making it seem like one is a full sphere. Amazing

Comment: what do you mean? actually at the beginning the left sphere is completely full, it then opens 180°

Comment: Oh yes! This is so perfect, using the screw modifier is brilliant. Thanks for all the effort everybody

Comment: Great, you can also duplicate the same sphere so that at the beginning you have 2 full spheres